# Utf-8 decode error in pyramid/WebOb request

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, paypal, pyramid

I found an error in the logs of a website of mine, in the log i got the body of the request, so i tried to reproduce that

This is what i got.

```python
>>> from mondishop.models import *
>>> from pyramid.request import *
>>> req = Request.blank('/')
>>> b = DBSession.query(Log).filter(Log.id == 503).one().payload.encode('utf-8')
>>> req.method = 'POST'
>>> req.body = b
>>> req.params
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/phas/virtualenv/mondishop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py", line 856, in params
    params = NestedMultiDict(self.GET, self.POST)
  File "/home/phas/virtualenv/mondishop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py", line 807, in POST
    vars = MultiDict.from_fieldstorage(fs)
  File "/home/phas/virtualenv/mondishop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/multidict.py", line 92, in from_fieldstorage
    obj.add(field.name, decode(value))
  File "/home/phas/virtualenv/mondishop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/multidict.py", line 78, in <lambda>
    decode = lambda b: b.decode(charset)
  File "/home/phas/virtualenv/mondishop/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 52: invalid start byte
>>> req.POST
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/phas/virtualenv/mondishop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py", line 807, in POST
    vars = MultiDict.from_fieldstorage(fs)
  File "/home/phas/virtualenv/mondishop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/multidict.py", line 92, in from_fieldstorage
    obj.add(field.name, decode(value))
  File "/home/phas/virtualenv/mondishop/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/multidict.py", line 78, in <lambda>
    decode = lambda b: b.decode(charset)
  File "/home/phas/virtualenv/mondishop/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 52: invalid start byte
>>>
```

The error is the same as the one i got i my log, so apparently something goes bad try to decoding the original post.

What is weird is that i get an error trying to utf-8 decode something that i just utf-8 encoded.

I cannot provide the content of the original request body because it contains some sensitive data (it's a paypal IPN) and i don't really have any idea on how to start addressing this issue.

Comment: There is a lot of data missing to help debug here. What type is the column in the database? There is probably a character you can remove to avoid the error, did you find it? (position 52). What does the string look like before you encode it to utf-8? I know you said you can't share it, but you probably can isolate the bad character and fake something for us that shows what you got from the database + its type (string vs unicode). How did you write it to the database if you can't read POST without throwing an exception?

Comment: Could you please attempt to reproduce the error, and provide a bug report: https://github.com/Pylons/webob/issues